# How do you get "android:" tag values in a Custom View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

There seems to be a lot of "similar" questions and answers to this scattered around which all refer to how to get a custom attribute from an `AttributeSet`. What I haven't been able to find so far is how to get an `android:` namespace tag:

```
    <com.custom.view.StatusThumbnail
        android:id="@+id/statusThumbnailContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

I would like to pull back the `layout_height` attribute from this custom component. Unfortunately from what I've read the closest I've got to how to do this is:

```
public StatusThumbnail(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    String height = attrs.getAttributeValue("android", "layout_height");
```

But this returns `null`.

Surely this isn't a rare thing to try and do?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The namespace should be "`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`" android is an alias declared in your xml file

Comment: What about the case that we need multiple namespaces in one single xml file. For example I've created a custom view as well as some new attributes for that custom view. Now I wanna set attributes using my own defined and android predefined attrs. in such case your approach still returns null. it sounds i can not access android predefined attrs. How may I resolve such this case?

Comment: Superb ! finally this worked : `attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "maxLength", 100)`

Comment: Thanks! That wokrs for me!

Answer (score -5):

First declare required attributes in :

res\attrs.xml

```
    <declare-styleable name="StatusThumbnail">
        <attr name="statusThumbnailattr" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

then in your XML layout declaration use the same attribute

```
<com.custom.view.StatusThumbnail
        android:id="@+id/statusThumbnailContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        statusThumbnailattr="some value"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Access using

```
public StatusThumbnail(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
TypedArray a=context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.StatusThumbnail);
this.mdColorDialogTitle=a.getString(R.styleable.StatusThumbnail_statusThumbnailattr);
}
```

Comment: Specifically didn't want custom tags - as mentioned in the question. Far too much pollution on this subject by similar answers.

Comment: I was trying to explain you additional implementation, anyways if feel like down voting I don't mind.

Comment: Remember to do `try { ... } finally { a.recycle(); }` as described on [TypedArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html)