# android defined attributes and custom attributes side by side on a custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view as well as corresponding custom attributes. For example

```
<declare-styleable name="stripbar">
    <attr name="flowDirection" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

and

```
public Stripbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
super(context, attrs);

TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.stripbar);
CharSequence flowDirection = ta.getString(R.styleable.stripbar_flowDirection);

String text = attrs.getAttributeValue("android", "text"); 
}
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ns">

            <com.ns.Stripbar
                    android:id="@+id/aaa"
                    ns:flowDirection="RightToLeft"
                    android:text=”yoo hoo”/>
```

I receive null value for attribute text. I’m also aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877172/how-do-you-get-android-tag-values-in-a-custom-view) and do not know how to resolve the issue.

To clarify, I need to obtain my custom attribute value as well as android predefined attribute value side by side?

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `R.styleable.stripbar` is actually an array of integers that contains just your `flowDirection` attribute.

To fix that, you should be able to replace your `context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.stripbar);` with  `context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[]{R.attr.flowDirection, android.R.attr.text});`

Then, you should be able to replace `ta.getString( R.styleable.stripbar_flowDirection )` with `ta.getString(0)` and get the text with `ta.getString(1)`.